# App Service restart when uploading content using ftp on site with .NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a main "App Service" with multiple sites on it. Some are based on .NET 4 and others in .NET Core 2. Even when I upload CSS or JS files through FTP on **.NET Core sites**, its restart all my sites even those on .NET 4, I try to turn off sites using App_Offline.htm but only uploading this file will restart all my sites.

I've tried the inverse thing, I upload files to a .NET 4 site and it does not restart any other site, even uploading App_Offline.htm or deleting it, there is no such behavior.

I don't know why this is happening with .NET Core sites,  or if there is a way to avoid this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: how have you hosted multiple apps, individual web apps OR multiple apps using virtual directories under one app?

Comment: multiple apps using virtual directories under one app

Comment: ok, I guess that's the reason behind this problem, how about you host them on separate apps? They are consuming the required resources (on App Service) anyway.

Comment: Only have 1 site with multiples apps, but, when I change a file on .NET Core app, It's restart all apps on site, but when I change a file on .NET4 nothing get restarted.

Comment: I guess that's the parent/child container isolation issue here. So, when you update something in parent container (app in the root) all the apps update and when you update the child only. no parent updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afortunally I got the answer.

- Problem was I upload app_offline.htm and then I upload .NET Core App, It's looks like Azure have some delay to shutdown .NET Core App, I only wait 1-2 mins to start uploading files, and no impact in any App running on same site (.NET4 and .NETCore)